# How to set worspace with MLPublishedPipelineRestAPITask in Azure DevOps Pipeline?

Tags: machine-learning, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to implement a CI pipeline for a Machine Learning model in Azure DevOps by forking the [MLOpsPython repo](https://github.com/microsoft/MLOpsPython). At the task where the pipeline is invoked, defined like this:

```
    - task: ms-air-aiagility.vss-services-azureml.azureml-restApi-task.MLPublishedPipelineRestAPITask@0
  displayName: 'Invoke ML pipeline'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(WORKSPACE_SVC_CONNECTION)'
    PipelineId: '$(AMLPIPELINE_ID)'
    ExperimentName: '$(EXPERIMENT_NAME)'
    WorkspaceName: 'prolab-ml-test-ws1'
    PipelineParameters: '"ParameterAssignments": {"model_name": "$(MODEL_NAME)"}, "tags": {"BuildId": "$(Build.BuildId)", "BuildUri": "$(BUILD_URI)"}, "StepTags": {"BuildId": "$(Build.BuildId)", "BuildUri": "$(BUILD_URI)"}'
```

This stage fails  with a 404 invoking the pipeline:

> https://westeurope.aether.ms/api/v1.0/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/wrong-workspace/PipelineRuns/PipelineSubmit/adcc2798-beae-4be7-aeb4-452411ca2f40

The workspace value in the url is incorrect - it appears to be the name of the resource group. How can I change the parameters for the `MLPublishedPipelineRestAPITask` task.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was my own stupid fault. The workspace settings are taken from the service connection in Azure DevOps, not from the parameters in the yml defining the task. I had the wrong workspace name in the service connection.